# Site with jQuery and CSS animation works everywhere except Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari

I'm pretty new in jQuery and the site from the link below works in FF, Chrome and Opera but not in Safari.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Reverse Records - Klick me</title>



      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>
  <div class='selector'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input id='1' type='checkbox'>
      <label for='1'>Option 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id='2' type='checkbox'>
      <label for='2'>Option 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id='3' type='checkbox'>
      <label for='3'>Option 3</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id='4' type='checkbox'>
      <label for='4'>Option 4</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="button1"></div>
</div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>


</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dceh27we/#&togetherjs=jM21DCBopb

How can it work there? Have I forgot something?

Comment: Please put an effort in your code. Get rid of the redundant things such as the scripts you are loading, and put those in the JS window. Make sure all tags are closed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, 
**check the css properties that you used are supported in Safari browser**

For example,

`animation-name,  -webkit-animation-name...`

These are used for naming for different browsers.

Comment: Did, doesn't help. It seems like Safari isn't recognizing the css data itself, since it works on any other webkit engined browser.

Comment: Ok, can you try any other websites in your safari browser, i don;'t know, may be just re-installing safari browser will be good.